# Is there a word for when you use a descriptor in place for a word/phrase you've forgotten?

Tags: meaning, names, phrasing

Best example I can give is a post I saw a while back where someone was trying to remember the name for a manta ray and described it as a sea pancake instead. Logically you could call it a sea pancake and most native speakers will get the gist of what you mean, but the actual name is still manta ray. Is there a word for that sort of phrasing in writing when you use nonstandard language but it still gets the point across or works as a valid name/descriptor?

Comment: ***stand-in*** word? That need not even be a word, maybe.

Comment: I would never ever take descriptor out for tea.

Answer (score 1):

Expressing [one thing in terms of another](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenning), which is what your friend seems to have done, may be put under the umbrella of '***kenning***', per the Oxford English Dictionary:

> One of the periphrastic expressions used instead of the simple name of a thing, characteristic of Old Teutonic, and esp. Old Norse, poetry.
>
> *Examples are oar-steed = ship, storm of swords = battle.
>
> The term is adopted from the mediæval Icelandic treatises on poetics, and is derived from the idiomatic use of kenna við or til, ‘to name after’.*

Wikipedia has a very detailed and apparently scholarly article on Kennings, which I have linked to above. It isn't very quotable and I can't vouch for its accuracy at all, things are more simply put at [YourDictionary.com:](http://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-kenning.html)

> A kenning is a figurative expression that replaces a name or a noun. Often it is a compound of two words and the words are hyphenated. Kennings are usually associated with Old Norse, Icelandic, and Anglo Saxon poetry.
>
> Modern Examples of Kennings:
>
> - Ankle biter = a very young child
> - Bean counter = a CPA or accountant
> - Bookworm = someone who reads a lot
> - Fender bender = slight car accident
> - Four-eyes = someone who wears glasses

Comment: The example the OP gave was of someone making up a phrase, not using an established idiom like these. Of course, all of these must have started out with someone making them up the first time.

Answer (score 0):

> **analogy** [noun] a comparison between two things, typically for the purpose of explanation or clarification. ...
>
> - *the syndrome is called deep dysgraphia because of its analogy to deep dyslexia*
>
> a thing which is comparable to something else in significant respects.

Comment: Hi james, please attribute your source.

Comment: ... or this may be removed (copyright issues).